# Why are Bessel function and Kloosterman sum similar?

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, bessel-functions

It is a convention to say Kloosterman sums and Bessel functions are similar.

There are papers talking about Bessel functions on $p$-adic group (associated with a representation) such as Baruch's: http://www2.math.technion.ac.il/~embaruch/GLn/func.pdf

But I did not see why it is related to classical Kloosterman sums even in the case of $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb Q_p)$.

Comment: It is explained e. g. by Sarnak in [Kloosterman, quadratic
forms and modular forms](http://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/~sofose/kloosterman_ps.pdf) (see the text around the display (16) there)

Comment: The one you mentioned by Sarnak is not very satisfying. I am still seeking angle from representation theory, such as Baruch's paper.

Comment: Were you able to calculate it and did not see how your calculation was related to Kloosterman sums, or were you unable to calculate it?

Comment: I don't know which corresponds to which. I am confused because the Bessel function on GL(2,Q_p) is associated with a representation whereas the Kloosterman sum only depends on three integer numbers (not Satake parameters).

Comment: This is kinda late, but for a generic principal series representation of $\mathrm{GL}_2\left( \mathbb{F}_q \right)$, induced from the characters $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$, we get $J_{\pi, \psi}
\pmatrix{ & 1 \\
a& } = q^{-1} \sum_{ \substack{x \in \mathbb{F}_q \\ xy=-a^{-1}} } \alpha_1^{-1}(x) \alpha_2^{-1}(y) \psi(x+y)$, which is a Kloosterman sum. These sort of formulas are given in Piatetski-Shapiro's book "Complex Representations of $GL(2,K)$ for Finite Fields $K$" (see page 61).